# Installing play framework

Tags: playframework

I am on windows 7 and I am trying to install play framework.

I created the environment variable in system variables with
**variable name:** *play*, **value:** *c:\webapp\play\*

When I am trying to run `play help` from commander it says

```
play is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or 
batch file and it is running only in the directory of c:webapp\play.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to add the directory containing the `play` executable to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To be able to run Play anywhere on the command line, create a `PLAY_HOME` environment variable pointing to the play folder, for e.g. `c:\play-2.0.1`, and add `%PLAY_HOME%` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: in were i add `%PLAY_HOME%` i created play_home as variable name and value as the path am having the play

Answer (score 10):

Muhammad is correct. The only thing I would add is this:
After saving the environment variables, I noticed that one must:

1. close ALL explorer windows
2. open a new one
3. open a new cmd prompt

and then I saw the play_home in the path and play worked everywhere.
For some reason, updating the environment variables didn't refresh existing windows.

**UPDATE:**
If you're in a hurry and feeling rebellious, open a cmd prompt window first, then kill explorer.exe, then restart explorer.exe in the cmd window.
That should refresh everything but be careful...

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I have set it up for others in the past.

Create a directory `c:\playframework`

Create two more inside of this

`framework` and `apps`

I then have a bat file called `env.bat` containing the following

```
set PATH=%path%;c:\playframework\framework\'
```

You can then run `env.bat` to make sure play is initialise.

Answer (score 3):

I realized that it doesn't work if you have a **space** in your path to the play framework.

So instead of

```
C:\Folder with space\PlayFramework
```

try

```
C:\FolderWithoutSpace\PlayFramework
```

This fixed it for me, guess it has to do with the play batch file which doesn't handle paths with spaces correctly. Stumbled upon this question, when searching for a solution, so it might help some other folks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open command prompt as administrator
2. `setx PATH "%PATH%;c:\path\to\play" /m`  <--substitute **c:\path\to\play** with your path
3. Re-open new command prompt and you can run **play** from anywhere

Comment: Thnx oscar it worked, but play -run not working in cmd

Answer (score 1):

To start a play project, an alternative is to download the activator and create a play project. Download the activator and add it to the environment variable.
Open a command prompt and use the following command to create a java project:
C:\ activator new project-name play-java
If you want to create a scala project
C:\ activator new project-name play-scala