# Installing Play! framework on Windows 8.1: What do I add to the path?

Tags: java, scala, frameworks, path, playframework

I am trying to install `Play`, and have been going through the [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msJH-YLropw). I have also tried for a couple hours now reading through the [installation guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Installing). Yet, I cannot find what it is that I need to add to the `environment variables` in order to get this to `Play` to work. I also am a little confused on how `javac` is suppose to work with this, as my understanding through another video is that I needed to add a `path` to `javac` as well.

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573654/installing-play-framework) that asks a very similar question, but the terminology is above me, and I would like to not mess this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `java -version` in a command line?  When you install the JDK, it will usually set itself up for you, so if that works, you don't need to do anything for it.  As for Play, unzip it to some location, eg `C:\path\to\playinstall`, and then add `C:\path\to\playinstall` to your `PATH` environment variable.  Alternatively use Typesafe Activator, it runs a UI in a browser that manages everything for you.

Comment: Yep! `java -version` and `javac -version` are up and running. I have a question regarding the use of `path` in `C:\path\to\playinstall`. Where is `path`, what is `path`, and am I over-thinking this? Because I am starting to think that I am haha.

Comment: Yes, I think you are over thinking it, path is wherever you want it to be, for example, you could put it in the root, eg, C:\play-2.2.1, or you could put it in program files (not recommended, spaces in the path can cause issues), but that would be C:\Program Files\play-2.2.1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my init_play.bat that I run in a console window.  Run it once when open a new console, then cd into your play app's directory and do play run...

```
path=%path%;C:\IanTools\play\play-2.2.1
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am answering this question for Windows users, and at the time of writing this, I am using `Windows 8.1`.

So after playing around with this for a while, I ended up thinking I had to delete my entire description of the `PATH` environment variable, but all you have to do is add to the `PATH` variable. What needs to be added is the location of your Play folder (which is recommended to be placed in the root), and also add the location of `JavaSDK`+`bin`, which should be located somewhere in the `Program Files` folder. Adding these is a simple copy and paste of the entire location of the folder (found in the browsing bar), and insertion into the `PATH` variable by editing the variable.

Be sure to go to the end of the value of the variable once clicking on `Edit`. Then, before pasting the location that was just copied, add a `;` after the previous entry. If you accidentally delete anything, (as I did), this could spell out some problems for your computer. If you do delete anything, then `Ctrl+z` or go so some similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779856/default-path-system-variable-for-windows) (<--- like this one). I hope that this is somewhat of a dummies guide to solving the matter, as several Youtube tutorials and threads did not seem to work entirely for me. Best of luck!